# programmatically select cell and segue to tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, segue

i have a main view (uitableviewcontroller) that have table and a button
the button is linked with modal segue to another view to add object to the table (on the main view )
and the cell is linked with modal segue to a tabbarcontroller which on the first tab display details about this object

i'm trying to automatically transition into the detail view (to the first tab ) after creating new object

i can't figure how to do it
using performSegueWithIdentifier fails with presentation already in progress
and using tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath i can't quite create the logic for this transition

help will be appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does the button have an associated action? If so you can use performselector to simulate the button push.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(buttonAction:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
```

If the problem of firing the segue failes due to presentation in progress, you can also use the method i mentioned above to call a method after a suitable delay to ensure that the view has presented. Probably you would use it in conjucntion with the viewDidAppear methods. I hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks that did help but i fixed the presentation in progress error by disabling the animation in the dismiss view that i had